# Best AJAX file upload control in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, file, file-upload

Can any one guide me which file upload is best for an ASP.NET MVC project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)
  I used this one, though it uses Flash
  it's very easy to implement
- [Silverlight File
  Upload](http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/)
- [NeatUpload](http://neatupload.codeplex.com/)
- [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)

These are the free ones I know. There are some you can buy but these get the job done.

Comment: if the MVC app is going to be consumed from iPads... Uploadify still works? I mean, it "mutate" to something compatible?

Comment: Uploadify is flash based. I don't know you can 'mutate' it actually